# kotlin rounding off in BigDecimal

Tags: kotlin, rounding, bigdecimal

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

BigDecimal(0.235).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) // 0.23

BigDecimal("0.235").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) // 0.24
```

In kotlin, when input 0.235 is given as double then the output is 0.23.
when input 0.235 is given as string then the output is 0.24

Here is the definition of ROUND_HALF_UP given in the documentation:

> Rounding mode where values are rounded towards the nearest
> neighbor. Ties are broken by rounding up.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

From the `BigDecimal` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)):

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new `BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a
>    `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1,
>    with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>    0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>    matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>    that is being passed *in* to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>    0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing `new BigDecimal("0.1")` creates a `BigDecimal` which
>    is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is
>    generally recommended that the [String
>    constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))
>    be used in preference to this one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in the first case you are calling the `BigDecimal` constructor using a floating point (read: not exact) literal.  Consider the following script (in Java):

```
BigDecimal blah = new BigDecimal(0.235d);
System.out.println(blah);
```

This prints `0.23499999999999998667732370449812151491641998291015625` in my demo tool.  That is, you are not actually passing in literal `0.235`, but rather a floating point approximation to it.  It so happens, in this case, that the actual literal value is slightly less than `0.235`, leading the round half up to result in `0.23` rather than `0.24`.